# Como poderia fazer para que o texto não saia duplicado

Tags: java

Estava desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java que basicamente cria uma matriz 4 x 4, que tem que contar e escrever quantos valores maiores que 10 ela possui, até consegui fazer isso, porém o texto que pede para o usuário digitar dois valores (o da linha e o da coluna) sempre aparece duplicado, já tentei fazer muitas coisas, porém não adiantou de muita coisa.

Código do programa:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int contagem = 0;

        int matriz[][] = new int [4][4];

        for (int linha = 0; linha < 4; linha++) {
            for (int coluna = 0; coluna < 4; coluna++) {
                System.out.println("\nInsira dois numeros, um para a coluna e outro para a linha = ");
                matriz[linha][coluna] = sc.nextInt();
                
                if (matriz[linha][coluna] > 10) {
                    contagem++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Na matriz existem: " + contagem + " numeros maiores que 10");
    }
}
```

[image: Problema]

Comment: Não cumprimente, não agradeça e não escreva *Resolvido* no título. Para marcar uma pergunta como resolvida marque uma resposta como aceita. Veja: [Como e porque aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) e [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sc.nextInt()` lê apenas um número, mas você está pedindo para o usuário digitar 2.

O segundo número que o usuário digitar irá continuar no buffer, e na próxima vez que você invocar `sc.nextInt()`, ele irá ler esse segundo número imediatamente, por isso o programa nem prontifica o usuário a digitar um número novamente, ele imprime `Insira dois numeros, um para a coluna e outro para a linha =`  e captura o segundo número que já foi digitado.

Mas o programa está certo, apenas o que você está pedindo como entrada está dando a impressão errada. Você deveria estar pedindo para o usuário inserir um único valor para a linha/coluna atual.

Ao invés de

```
System.out.println("\nInsira dois numeros, um para a coluna e outro para a linha = ");
```

Faria mais sentido pedir

```
System.out.println("\nInsira um número para a posição ["+linha+"]["+coluna+"] = ");
```

Comment: valeu aí mano, só estou achando estranho que quando eu boto para executar o programa no terminal, aparece duas vezes o texto pedindo para informar dois valores

Comment: Ele aparece porque o usuário digitou 2 números. Se o usuário digitar 3, em seguida irá aparecer 3 mensagens, por razões explicadas na resposta.

Comment: então como eu resolveria isso?

Comment: ok, deu certo aqui, obrigado :)